# What do Response.Cache.SetCacheability and Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory mean?

Tags: asp.net

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
```

While searching for authentication, I found the above two lines written. What do they mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[HttpCachePolicy.SetCacheability Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.setcacheability(v=VS.100).aspx)

> NoCache: Sets the Cache-Control: no-cache header. Without a field name, the directive applies to the entire request and a shared (proxy server) cache must force a successful revalidation with the origin Web server before satisfying the request. With a field name, the directive applies only to the named field; the rest of the response may be supplied from a shared cache.

[HttpCachePolicy.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.setallowresponseinbrowserhistory.aspx)

> When HttpCacheability is set to NoCache or ServerAndNoCache the Expires HTTP header is by default set to -1; this tells the client not to cache responses in the History folder, so that when you use the back/forward buttons the client requests a new version of the response each time.

Answer (score 5):

The first one tells the browser not to cache this page ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4yy9w70.aspx)), and the second one tells the browser not to include this page in the browse history ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.setallowresponseinbrowserhistory.aspx)).

Comment: "Google is your friend" is not an acceptable answer and is only frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

What I found out by a hard way and a day of the research that having `Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.ServerAndNoCache)`

in `Global.asax.cs` file:

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.ServerAndNoCache);
}
```

helps handling refreshing pop up window with a new data in IE browser.

Setting that, invokes a controller second time the pop up window is opened and refreshes the data inside from the server.

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

These lines prevent the page from being cached.

Answer (score 0):

In this `cache` is controlled by using the following statement:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Comment: could you add more to your answer?

Comment: doesn't answer the question.